# Getting essential computer info for network admins

Tags: powershell

I recently had to install VNC on mass across a lot of computers on a domain and needed some info about their PC, for example:

1. Host name
2. Username
3. MAC Address
4. IPv4 Address
5. Domain name

Once all of this info is gathered, it is compiled into a text file and uploaded to a FTP server. To save files from being conflicted with the same name, I set each file to be named the name of the user.

This is the first ever script and first experience I have had with Powershell so please tell me if there is anything I can improve.

```
function Get-MACAddress {
    ipconfig /all | findstr "Physical" | Where-Object {$_.length -lt 58}
}
function Get-IPAddress {
    ipconfig | findstr "IPv4 Address"
}
function Get-HostName {
   get-content env:computername
}
function Get-UserName{
     get-content env:UserName
}
function Get-DomainName{
get-content env:USERDOMAIN
}
function CreateCSVdocument {
    Get-MACAddress | New-Item C:\Users\$($env:username)\Documents\$($env:username).txt -type file     -force 
    Add-Content C:\Users\$($env:username)\Documents\$($env:username).txt " "

Get-IPAddress | Add-Content C:\Users\$($env:username)\Documents\$($env:username).txt
Add-Content C:\Users\$($env:username)\Documents\$($env:username).txt " "

Add-Content C:\Users\$($env:username)\Documents\$($env:username).txt "Hostname:"
Get-Hostname | Add-Content C:\Users\$($env:username)\Documents\$($env:username).txt
Add-Content C:\Users\$($env:username)\Documents\$($env:username).txt " "

Add-Content C:\Users\$($env:username)\Documents\$($env:username).txt "User:"
Get-UserName | Add-Content C:\Users\$($env:username)\Documents\$($env:username).txt
Add-Content C:\Users\$($env:username)\Documents\$($env:username).txt " "

Add-Content C:\Users\$($env:username)\Documents\$($env:username).txt "Domain:"
Get-DomainName | Add-Content C:\Users\$($env:username)\Documents\$($env:username).txt
}
function FTPUpload {
$Dir="C:\Users\$($env:username)\Documents\$($env:username).txt"    

#ftp server 
$ftp = "ftpserver" 
$user = "username" 
$pass = "password"  

$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient 

$webclient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($user,$pass)  

#list every sql server trace file 
foreach($item in (dir $Dir "$($env:username).txt")){ 
    "Uploading $item..." 
    $uri = New-Object System.Uri($ftp+$item.Name) 
    $webclient.UploadFile($uri, $item.FullName) 
} 

}
Get-DomainName
Get-IPAddress
Get-MACAddress
Get-HostName
Get-UserName
CreateCSVdocument
FTPUpload
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks quite fine to me.

I'm mainly surprised by the massive duplication in the `CreateCSVdocument` function:

> ```
> function CreateCSVdocument {
>     Get-MACAddress | New-Item C:\Users\$($env:username)\Documents\$($env:username).txt -type file -force 
>     Add-Content C:\Users\$($env:username)\Documents\$($env:username).txt " "
>
> Get-IPAddress | Add-Content C:\Users\$($env:username)\Documents\$($env:username).txt
> Add-Content C:\Users\$($env:username)\Documents\$($env:username).txt " "
>
> Add-Content C:\Users\$($env:username)\Documents\$($env:username).txt "Hostname:"
> Get-Hostname | Add-Content C:\Users\$($env:username)\Documents\$($env:username).txt
> Add-Content C:\Users\$($env:username)\Documents\$($env:username).txt " "
> ```

It would be better to introduce a variable there and use that, for example:

```
function CreateCSVdocument {
    $Dir="C:\Users\$($env:username)\Documents\$($env:username).txt" 

    Get-MACAddress | New-Item $Dir -type file -force 

    Add-Content $Dir " "    
    Get-IPAddress | Add-Content $Dir
    Add-Content $Dir " "

    Add-Content $Dir "Hostname:"
    Get-Hostname | Add-Content $Dir
    Add-Content $Dir " "
```

Actually, this is still too repetitive.
Probably there is a better way to output all the text and pipe the whole thing to `... | Add-Content $Dir` once at the end,
but I don't know how to do that in powershell.

---

The formatting is inconsistent:

- In function definitions, sometimes you put a space between function name and `{` and sometimes you don't:

  ```
  function Get-MACAddress {
  function Get-UserName{
  ```

  I recommend to put a space always, consistently.
- Indentation is inconsistent:

  - You correctly indented the body of `Get-MACAddress`, `Get-IPAddress` and others
  - But you didn't follow the same logic in `Get-HostName`, `Get-UserName`, `Get-DomainName` and others

Comment: Thank's Janos, this has made it look a lot neater. I have put the 'Add-Content $Dir " "' to create a new line as when I have tried other code to create a new line it does not work. could you please advice?

Comment: @Phasmatis I don't see why that wouldn't work.

Comment: it seems to write it in the text file also, for example if I did /n it would create a new line but write /n in the text document also.

Answer (score 1):

The script looks sound and functional, and quite a useful script considering it's your first. This is how I would restructure it for brevity and readability:

- I would do away with the functions altogether, unless this is part of a larger script where you will call them multiple times.
- The bulk of the script can be condensed using `@" ... "@`. You can insert new lines to the output, and include the information you need:

  ```
  $outputfile = "C:\Users\$($env:username)\Documents\$($env:username).txt"

  @"
  $(ipconfig /all | ? { $_ -ilike "*physical*" -and $_.length -lt 58 })

  $(ipconfig | ? { $_ -ilike "*IPv4 Address*" })

  Hostname: $env:computername

  User: $env:UserName

  Domain: $env:USERDOMAIN
  "@ | Out-File $outputfile
  ```
- Notice I didn't use `findstr` - there is functionality in Powershell for this. You touched on it when testing `$_.length -lt 58`.
- Declaring `$Dir` would now be unnecessary due to declaring `$outputfile` on the first line:

  > ```
  > $Dir="C:\Users\$($env:username)\Documents\$($env:username).txt"
  > ```
- I don't have access to an FTP server to test the upload, but this loop is suspicious:

  > ```
  > foreach($item in (dir $Dir "$($env:username).txt")){ ... }
  > ```

  Using `dir` is fine, but note this is an alias of the Powershell command `Get-ChildItem`. The loop condition here amounts to getting a single file, whose name and path is already stored in `$outputfile` on the first line. Therefore the entire loop is unnecessary:

  ```
  $item = Get-Item -Path $outputfile
  "Uploading $($item.FullName)..." 
  $uri = New-Object System.Uri($ftp+$item.Name)
  $webclient.UploadFile($uri, $item.FullName)
  ```